# How can I properly import Sass on my own CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, compass-sass

I am learning sass now and I am amazed by its simplicity but I have a problem in compiling or importing.

Because if I try to view my style.css it contains also the styling of the Bootstrap Framework and also the other third party css.

Here's my setup hope you can give me some idea about this.

**styles.scss**

```
// Import Bootstrap Compass integration
@import "bootstrap-compass";

// Import custom Bootstrap variables
@import "bootstrap-variables";

// Import Bootstrap for Sass
@import "bootstrap";

// Import Font Awesome
@import "font-awesome-compass";
@import "font-awesome";

// sass breakpoint
@import "../assets/bower_components/breakpoint-sass/stylesheets/_breakpoint.scss";
```

**mystyles.scss**

```
@import 'styles';
@import 'mystyles-mixins';
@import 'mystyles-variables';

.... my styles below
```

As you can see the style.scss is for importing only. 
Can you help me with this? The output is fine but I don't like what I see on the page source because it looks like my css is owned by bootstrap :-)

I am using Compass with sass

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove third party comments when I compile my SCSS/SASS and add my own banner (comments). You can see on [bootstrap's CSS file](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css) they added `/*! */` at the top comment. Meaning when you compile it will keep that comment. You can read more about this on the [documents](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#comments).

So if you remove all the third party forced comments eg. `/*! Comment */` and add your own to your first import it should look much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand your issue, and this should help. Try linking to the css instead of importing the resources directly into your sass files. For example, with bootstrap, remove the @imports for bootstrap css and put something similar to the following in your page header, depending on what version you're using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

This will separate your stylesheets from their stylesheets, but you will still have both available to use in your project.

Comment: I advise against this as it adds on to http requests resulting in a slower load just for source code aesthetics.

Comment: You can cache the resource which should help with the load speed, but I agree that source code aesthetics provide minimal value, especially when compared to load speed.

Comment: @l3fty this is not exactly true; it does add to the *number* of http requests, but may actually be more efficient. Since bootstrap.css in example above is coming from their CDN, this takes advantage of browser's parallelism, as these requests will be made simultaneously. You are also benefitting from serving only your own CSS from your server while offloading Bootstrap to their CDN.